# Applying patterns to introduced text after Insert

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select distinct SUBSTR(dni,4,2) as counter_dni 
from persona
where SUBSTR(dni,4,2)<=10
order by counter_dni;
```

It returns:

```
1 - 1  
2 - 10  
3 - 2  
4 - 3
```

The first number is just the row number, using Oracle SQL developer.
The problem is that I have multiple inserts like:

```
DNI1  
DNI2  
DNI3
```

until DNI 15 or so.
What i want to do is **replace** the format **after** DNI with a specific pattern like:

```
DNI0001  
DNI0010
```

filling the gaps with 0 in a lenght of 4 digits for example. How can i do that **after** the rows were inserted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
(select REGEXP_REPLACE(dni,'([0-9])+$', LPAD('\1',5,'0')) from counter_dni;
```

to check the output and

```
update counter_dni set dni = (REGEXP_REPLACE(dni,'([0-9])+$', LPAD('\1',5,'0')));
```

to update your values